# How can I configure an Apache-Mina sftp client to use a proxy?

Tags: sftp, apache-mina

I want to use Apache MINA as an `sftp` client within a Java application.  This application will make an outbound connection through a HTTPS proxy to a remote server.  I will need to set authentication details for connecting to the proxy somewhere.

I want to obtain an instance of `org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClient` which is running over an `ssh` connection through the proxy.

I have these imports:

```
import org.apache.sshd.client.SshClient;
import org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientProxyConnector;
import org.apache.sshd.client.session.ClientSession;
import org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClient;
import org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClientFactory;
```

And this is the code that I've written thus far:

```
    // proxy
    ClientProxyConnector proxy = ????;

    // ssh
    SshClient sshClient = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
    sshClient.setClientProxyConnector( proxy );
    sshClient.start();

    ClientSession sshSession = sshClient.connect( "example.org" ).getSession();

    // sftp
    SftpClientFactory factory = SftpClientFactory.instance();
    SftpClient client = factory.createSftpClient(sshSession);
```

Questions:

- Do I need an instance of `ClientProxyConnector` to do what I'm trying to do?
- How can I obtain an instance of a `ClientProxyConnector` and configure it with the proxy authentication details?

Answer (score 2):

To go over a proxy you should create the `ClientSession` with `HostConfigEntry` which allows [to specify a proxy](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/2fc98f7a21a7b83d2b2bc72d48a2194caa7f8fd1/docs/internals.md#ssh-jumps).

```
HostConfigEntry host = new HostConfigEntry("", "example.org", 22, "username", 
    proxyUser + "@" + proxyHost + ":" + proxyPort);
ClientSession sshSession = sshClient.connect(host).getSession();
```

The purpose of `ClientProxyConnector` is [something else](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/2fc98f7a21a7b83d2b2bc72d48a2194caa7f8fd1/docs/internals.md#proxy--sslh-protocol-hooks).